# MVC, Login validation with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation, model-view-controller

I have a project build in C#, MVC. I am trying to build a solution in one view where something will be shown only if you are logged in.
I know how to do this with Razor, but the view is a .html.
Is it possible to use Angular to validate if a user is logged in?

**EDIT**

I have tried to follow the suggestion from Valverde. The following is my current setup but I am getting this error in consol:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: loginServiceProvider <- loginService
```

**MatchController:**

```
[Route("api/Match/userAuthentication")]
    public IHttpActionResult GenerateTournamentTree()
    {
        bool isLoggedIn = false;
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            isLoggedIn = true;
        }

        return Json(new { Result = isLoggedIn });

    }
```

I am not sure if the return type should be in Json?

**fightCardController.js:**

```
angular.module('FightCardModule').controller("FightCardController",
    ['$scope', '$modal', '$http', '$routeParams', 'guidGenerator', 'eventBus', domainName + "Service", 'MatchModelFactory', 'loginService',
function ($scope, $modal, $http, $routeParams, guidGenerator, eventBus, domainService, modelFactory, loginService) {

$scope.isUserLoggedIn = false;
        loginService.isUserLoggedIn().success(function (data) {
            $scope.isuserLoggedIn = data;
        });

})();
```

**loginService.js:**

```
app.factory('loginService', ['$http', function ($http) {
return {
    isUserLoggedIn: function () {
        url = "/Match/userAuthentication"
        return $http.get(url);
    }
}
}]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so with ValVerdes help I figured out a solution. Thank you Valverde!

**My View:**

```
<div ng-show="isLoggedIn == 1" ... >
You are logged in!
</div>
```

**My controller:**

```
        [Route("api/Match/userAuthentication")]
    public IHttpActionResult userAuthentication(List<String> stringOfLoginStatus)
    {
        int isLoggedIn = Int32.Parse(stringOfLoginStatus[0]);
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            isLoggedIn = 1;
        }

        return Json(new { Result = isLoggedIn });

    }
```

**My controller.js:**

```
$scope.isLoggedIn;

    $scope.isUserLoggedIn = function () {

        var isCurrentUserLoggedIn;
        var stringOfLoginStatus = new Array();
        stringOfLoginStatus[0] = 0;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Api/Match/userAuthentication",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(stringOfLoginStatus),
            success: function (data) {
                $scope.isLoggedIn = data.Result;
                data.Result;
            },
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create `service` that check if the user is logged in:

```
app.factory('loginService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        isUserLoggedIn: function () {
            url = // address to your Action in Controller that returns true/false
                  // for example: 'UserController/IsUserLoggedId'
            return $http.get(url);
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then you can use it in your controller:

```
app.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', 'loginService', function ($scope, loginService) {
    $scope.isUserLoggedIn = false;
    loginService.isUserLoggedIn().success(function (data) {
        $scope.isuserLoggedIn = data;
    };
};
```

And now you can show or hide any `html block` using `ng-show` or `ng-hide`:

```
<div ng-show="isUserLoggedIn" ... >
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Valverde. Sorry for the late reply! I have tried to follow your suggestion and I have edited my question with what I have done up until now.

Comment: Hi Casper, It's a angular error `[$injector:unpr]` when Angular cannot find such module or provide or something else. The most common reason is the file that isn't attached. Make sure that you didn't forget to load `js` file with `loginService`. For example `<script src="pathToFile/loginService.js"></script>`

Comment: And return type shouldn't necessary by `Json`. You just can send `bool` value (even object) and `$http` service will parse the response to Json independently.